# Android studio database inspector does not show any databases

Tags: android, android-studio

I am on Android studio 4.1 beta 1 . I installed my app on my device and opened Database Inspector and nothing shows up . Am I supposed to do anything else ?

[image]

I am using room database . I can see the database on device . Why is the database not showing up in database inspector?

Comment: I thought database inspector is available in Canary 6 build! Which are you using?

Comment: version 4.1  is beta now .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like its problem with device . If you have some custom rom installed then you might run into this issue . Link to the issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/159432618

Comment: I am using Android Studio4.1 stable. No database is showing . Take a look here ; https://imgur.com/RsYj5ql

Comment: I guess that's it. I have a custom ROM installed, and it just says deploy your app to a device running API level 26 or higher, or select a debuggable process to inspect. I'm running API 29 and have already selected the debuggable process; still nothing.

Comment: restarting device worked for me

Comment: They should add this on docs. Or fix it

Answer (score 28):

In my case, it showed me the same process a lot of times. And none of them worked.

The solution was Invalidating the Cache:

> File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart -> Invalidate and restart

After that everything started working again.

Comment: Still true for Dolphin | 2021.3.1 unless: it didn't show any processes at all

Answer (score 22):

If you are using **Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1** then **Database Inspector** is under **App Inspection**. As below.

[image]

Answer (score 20):

A workaround is to restart your device. Works for me

Comment: This worked for me. One day it suddenly stopped working and a restart fixed it.

Answer (score 11):

I solved this problem by uninstall and then installing app again. Formerly when I had face to this issue, I could run database inspector just by close/open app but now it start working just by uninstalling

**Update**

after more working with database inspector I understand some times it just needs a few seconds to connect and no need to do anything else

Answer (score 8):

I face 2 cases:

- First time connect to my device and database does not show, then i do an action to modify database -> database will show.
- After I use ADB Idea to clean app data or uninstall (or go to settings and clear cache or uninstall app) -> database does not show -> restart device -> database will show

Comment: This is the only that worked for me on Motorola One phone

Comment: Can confirm that restarting the device solves the issue on a Motorola One.

Comment: In the first case, SELECT query was not enough, I had to INSERT something

Answer (score 3):

Well here is what was happening with me -
Android Studio wouldn't pick up my connected device at all with the message "*Error initializing adb : android debug bridge not found*" when I tried to use Device File Explorer.

Turned out my project level sdk wasn't set correctly. Fixing that worked.

File -> Project Structure
In Project, select valid Project SDK
In Modules -> myapp_android -> Dependencies, select a valid Module SDK.

You should now be able to select connected devices from the database inspector. Flush your cache  and restart (File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart and select "Invalidate Caches and Restart") for good measure.

Answer (score 2):

In My Case, I forgot to open the **database** view inside the **Database Inspector** window as mentioned in the screenshot. Click on the *database* menu option as highlighted in yellow.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps,

1. View -> Tool Windows -> App Inspection
2. Run the project
3. Then you can see the "**Database Inspection**"

Database Inspection in android studio arctic fox 2020.3.1 patch 3

[image: [![][1]][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGyjz.png]

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was using an emulator and I **came to know that its mentioned and configured storage was about full**.

So **I just wiped all data of emulator** and restarted the app inspection tab now this time I was able to view the db tables in the inspector window.

Answer (score 1):

Still so many problems with this how did it make it into stable? open the database inspector close your app reopen your app, app crashes,

Start your app open the database inspector restart your app, database inspector is gone cannot be brought back without uninstalling and reinstalling your app

Great

Answer (score 1):

Enable the "keep database connection open". I think its not showing because of .close(). See the image for your reference.

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtnYJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, I Open the Layout inspector and after that, I open the Database inspector, It works for me. seems like a bug of android studio

Answer (score 1):

had to restart emulator and started working again

Answer (score 0):

I face this issue on many devices. Kill the app process and run again. The application should be in the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Every time I faced with this issue, I'd unplugged the usb cable, then plugged it again. Then make sure the database inspector window is open. After that, every time the database is accessed, it'd appear in the window

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had two databases in assets under the same directory and only one was showing on the inspector no mater how many times I killed and restarted the process. In the end I found that it was not showing up because I needed to store the second database file in a separate folder

structure
assets > folder > db_file.db
assets > other_folder.db > other_db_file.db

such that the folder and the database file had the same name.

Example
assets > my_database.db > my_database.db

After that, both databases showed up on the database inspector

Answer (score 0):

I was emptying the cache (**cache** and **code_cache**) at each startup of my application.

When I did comment the line and stop deleting the cache, and unplug/plug back the phone, I got the database inspector showing my tables back again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select debug build variant.
2. Keep the device connected and deploy the app on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting app cache in simulator worked for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

**New Way to see Database Inspector**

In new android studio versions, "**Database Inspector**" is display inside "**App Inspector**" in bottom bar options, Just expend App Inspector:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have the targetSdk set to 34 change it to 33.
Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The minSdk version needs to be 26 and above, I set it to 27 and it works, I had the same problem.