# Android Studio. "Database Inspector is loading"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-room, database-inspector

For some reason my Database Inspector is not working. It's just showing me "Loading message" for almost an hour (yep, I waited an hour for this). I already tried Invalidate cache and restart, unplug/plug a device, app reinstall. No effect.
[image]
Device File Explorer is working fine, same with Layout Inspector. I can even locate database files
[image]

But Database Inspector just loading without any progress.

Do you have any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I guess I've finally found the answer.

According to this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62725344/7928847 database inspector have some problems with custom ROMs (such as mine `LineageOS`). I tried using an emulator and database inspector is working as it should with it.

So, in this issue - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/159432618 Google dev suggests to disable SELinux. Mine now in `Enforcing` mode. I've switched it to `Permissive` and now my database inspector is finally working.

Answer (score 1):

For me the resolution was to uninstall the app from the (simulated) device. Afterwords, the inspector was working again.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your android studio or app component update.
and try these steps:

1. Invalidate cache and restart.
2. Clean project.
3. Rebuild Project.
4. unplug/plug a device.

Comment: As I already mentioned I tried all of this things, but problem is still here

Comment: Did your Android studio is up to date with the latest version.?

Comment: Yes. 4.2.1 version

Comment: Well, it's quite strange. It shouldn't act like that.
Is it happening for all projects or only for some specific project. ?

Comment: For all projects. I tried few with room database included

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall the app on your Device
2. Change the version of your database

   ```
   private static final int DATABASE_VERSION =1;
   ```
3. Re-install the App.