# Database Not showing in app inspector(Android Studio)

Tags: android, mysql, android-studio

I am trying to create a database for my project but when I created a database it's not showing in my app inspector.
I also tried with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62355581/android-studio-database-inspector-does-not-show-any-databases) but I am still faced with this.
[image]

[image]

How I fix this, Thank you.